RestTemplate ResourceAccessException :Read Timed Out
I have a SpringBoot_3.2.1/JDK17/Tomcat10 application where I am using a RestTemplate.
At some point it makes a call :
RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();
template.exchange( ,,,, );

My call executes a stored procedure that runs longer than 3 minutes. And in exactly 3 minutes I am getting an exception:

org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException : I/O Error on POST request for  : Read Timed out
....
Caused by : java.netSocketTimeoutException : Read Timed out

I tried to pass arguments to JVM :
-Dsun.net.client.defaultConnectionTimeout=600000 
-Dsun.net.client.defaultReadTimeout=600000 

I also tried to set it programmatically :
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(getClientHttpRequestFactory());

//Override timeouts in request factory
private SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory getClientHttpRequestFactory() {

    SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory clientHttpRequestFactory  = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();
    clientHttpRequestFactory.setConnectTimeout(600000);
    clientHttpRequestFactory.setReadTimeout(600000);
    return clientHttpRequestFactory;
}

I am still getting a Read Timed out Exception after exactly 3 minutes. Two questions :

Where is this 3 minute time out is set?
How can I increase the timeout so the application doesn't fail?

We have Red Hat Linux version 9.4

Verify and Set Timeouts in Tomcat
If your application is running within Tomcat, ensure that Tomcat's connector settings do not impose a timeout. You can check or modify the connector's connectionTimeout in server.xml:
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="600000"
           redirectPort="8443" />

Use HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory
Instead of using SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory, you can use HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory, which is more flexible and reliable for handling timeouts.
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(getHttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory());

private HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory getHttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory() {
    int timeout = 600000; // 10 minutes
    RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom()
            .setConnectTimeout(timeout)
            .setSocketTimeout(timeout)
            .build();

    CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.custom()
            .setDefaultRequestConfig(config)
            .setConnectionManager(new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager())
            .build();

    return new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(client);
}


Thank for the response. Unfortunately Setting up Timeout in Tomcat didn't help, I am still getting a Read Timed out Exception after 3 minutes. and in the code "HttpComponensClientHttpRequestFactory requires "HttpClient" type parameter and compiler complains about CloseableHttpClient type

To verify the underlying issue, it is better to enable loggers for HTTP request. Based on client used, enable the debug loggers. Since , as per the excerpt shared, you are getting java.net Socket timeout exception. Run your service by setting the system property or adding the parameter while running the application (-Djdk.httpclient.HttpClient.log=all).
It should display the time it took to start the socket and the socket timeout value defined.
If from client it shows the time as you have defined in the code. It is possible, socket is getting closed by network layer or server-side.
Enabling loggers can help you out in analysing the issue.
Additionally, you can also use resttemplate builder to define timeout value at client.

setting read timeout on the client side is not helping, may be because the service itself is rejecting the request after 3 minutes. You must talk with the service owner about increasing the timeout or discuss the execution time of the procedure with him.
If the stored procedure is returning something then waiting for the response is fine but if it is not then probably you must try an asynchronous call.
Another angle is the socket timeout at the OS level. please refer
